# making a web service faster (wcf)

Tags: c#, wcf

We are trying to write an inner wcf service between 2 servers.
one off the application is a server application for our clients.
the clients sends us files and we then process them and converting them.
this whole process takes some time mean while the client session is open, i dont this using async is possible?  which way can we make this methodology faster ? 
keep in mind that we have aprox 1000 files an hour ...each client sends up to 200 files an hour also 
G

Comment: consider streaming transfer mode

Comment: why streaming ? i need the whole file to start processing ?

Comment: Where is the bottleneck currently? On the network? Or in your processing? And what are the files? (roughly, I mean)

Comment: my bottle neck is at the processing, we keep the client on the session until the processing is over and then the client close the session and send another file. so the client sending the files slowly then needed. there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)) by Juval Lowy is all about one-way services, wcf call-back methods, etc.  It should show you how to set your services up to handle what you're looking for.

One-way services make the call asynchronous - fire and forget.  Setting up a call-back does what it sounds like - you can specify a service/method to be called back after a method executes.

Better yet, check out chapter 5 in Lowy's Programming WCF Services ([link](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805494/)).  It goes into MUCH greater detail than the article above.

I think the first link is enough to get started though.

Answer (score 2):

You could to send an address to be called back when that file processing is done and it will notify the consumer server. Or to use a message queue on both ends.